# string.replace seriously broken with \

Tags: c#, string, replace

```
"C://test/test/test.png" -> blub

    blub = blub.Replace(@"/", @"\");

result = "C:\\\\test\\test\\test.png"
```

how does that make sense? It replaces a single / with two \

?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, hope you stay a long while and learn and teach :) And a hint: When you find "bugs" like this, assume that it is your code or your assumptions which are flawed, 99 out of a 100 times (at least), that's what it boils down to. In this case, if the string replace method really was flawed like you indicate, it would'be been fixed or yanked from the library a long time ago.

Comment: If a function so simple was actually broken, do you really believe that you would be the first one to notice it?

Comment: Oh, and, "genius"? String.Replace is not part of C#. It's part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Stop nitpicking, this is a simple mistake to make, I've made it myself where I actually did the opposite, I dumped an incorrectly replaced string to a file, noticed the doubled escapes and thought everything was OK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually working:

```
string blub = "C://test/test/test.png";
string blub2 = blub.Replace(@"/", @"\");

Console.WriteLine(blub);
Console.WriteLine(blub2);
```

Output:

```
C://test/test/test.png
C:\\test\test\test.png
```

BUT viewing the string in the debugger does show the effect you describe (and is how you would write the string literal in code without the @).

I've noticed this before but never found out why the debugger chooses this formatting.

Comment: Because if the debugger didn't choose this formatting, it'd be giving ambiguous output all the time.  (How would the debugger output strings that contain quotes if it didn't use the escape characters?).

Comment: I guess that makes sense then :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the debugger, that helped me understand it.

Answer (score 8):

No, it doesn't.

What you're seeing is the properly formatted string according to C# rules, and since the output you're seeing is shown as though you haven't prefixed it with the `@` character, every backslash is doubled up, because that's what you would have to write if you wanted that string in the first place.

Create a new console app and write the result to the console, and you'll see that the string looks like you wanted it to.

So this is just an artifact of how you look at the string (I assume the debugger).

Answer (score 3):

The \ character in C# is the escape character, so if you are going to use it as a \ character you need two - otherwise the next character gets treated specially (new line etc).

See [What character escape sequences are available? (C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The character `\` is a special character, which changes the meaning of the character after it in string literals. So when you refer to  `\` itself, it needs to be escaped: `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "escape characters".

Answer (score 1):

Its done what it should.
`"\\"` is the same as `@"\"`

"\" is an escape character. Without the verbatim indicator "@" before a string a single \ is shown as `"\\"`

Answer (score 0):

You should think twice before saying something like that....

The string.Replace function is basic functionality that has been around for a long time.... Whenever you find you have a problem with something like that, it's probably not the function that is broken, but your understanding or use of it.