# Backslash escaping issue

Tags: c#, serialization, escaping, javascriptserializer

I have the following code:

```
search.UserToken = string.Format(@"{0};{1}", pi.Username, pi.Password)
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = jss.Serialize(obj);
```

Where `pi.Username` consists of the domain\username. This object is then serialized using the `JavaScriptSerializer` before it's sent via a web request to an API.

The problem I have is that the value sent ends up with four backslashes between the domain and the username as on the creation of the string the initial single backslash is escaped and then both these are escaped again during serialization.

How do I prevent this so that it's not escaped twice?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What happens if you do a .Replace(@"\\",@"\"); before you serialize it?

Comment: It is not possible that "on the creation of the string" (i.e. in the code you posted) that the single backslash would be doubled. Much more likely is that you are looking at the string in the debugger, and seeing the debugger's own presentation of the string, which will include escaping to make clear the difference between an actual backslash, and other escaped characters the debugger will present (e.g. `'\t'`, `'\r'`, `'\n'`, etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.replace seriously broken with ∖](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787933/string-replace-seriously-broken-with)

Comment: @PeterDuniho The issue still stands though that after serialization there are too many backslashes in the string and it's seen as an invalid login

Comment: Then please fix your question so that a) you describe the problem accurately, and b) you present [a good, complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for your problem. You can check the code snippet below:

```
[TestClass]
public class JavascriptSerializerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEscapeOnJavascriptSerializer()
    {
        const string replaceableToken = "[replace_here]";
        var user = @"domain\user".Replace(@"\", replaceableToken);
        const string password = "123456";

        var token = new Token { Value = string.Format("{0};{1}", user, password) };
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var jsonObject = serializer.Serialize(token);
        jsonObject = jsonObject.Replace(replaceableToken, @"\");
        Assert.AreEqual("{\"Value\":\"domain\\user;123456\"}", jsonObject);
    }
}

public class Token
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Explanation**

The JavaScriptSerializer class calls internally the method *HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(input)*, that adds the additional backslashes, by calling this method http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Util/HttpEncoder.cs,c0289ba7b2d459e5.
Another option would be to replace the *HttpEncoder*, but it seems too much for me :-).

Comment: Awesome, that sorted it.